# Return comma separated string from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to return a comma separated string from loop.

At the moment when I console.log it gives me this on each line.

> used vehicles;3374304;1;;;evar1=44377AA|evar49=undefined:null ContentServer?pagename=eUsed/script/usedcars-compare:784
>   used vehicles;3407554;1;;;evar1=61671CA|evar49=undefined:null ContentServer?pagename=eUsed/script/usedcars-compare:784
>   used vehicles;3374316;1;;;evar1=44377AA|evar49=undefined:null

I need this:

> used vehicles;3374304;1;;;evar1=44377AA|evar49=undefined:null,used vehicles;3407554;1;;;evar1=61671CA|evar49=undefined:null, used vehicles;3374316;1;;;evar1=44377AA|evar49=undefined:null

Here is my code:

```
function compareTrackingValues(){

    var getPostcode = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentPageData')),
        postcode = getPostcode.vehicleSessionData.location_entry,
        convertCompareObj,
        vehicleObj = [],
        vehicleInfo = {};

        for(var key in vehicleData){

            vehicleInfo = {};

            vehicleInfo.vehicleID = vehicleData[key].vehicleId;
            vehicleInfo.dealerID = vehicleData[key].vendor.vendorCode;
            vehicleInfo.scheme = vehicleData[key].vehicleId.schemes;
            vehicleInfo.owner = vehicleData[key].vendor.ownerCode;

            vehicleObj.push(vehicleInfo);



            s.Products = "used vehicles;"+vehicleInfo.vehicleID;
            s.Products += ";1;;;evar1="+vehicleInfo.dealerID ;
            s.Products += "|evar49="+vehicleInfo.scheme;
            s.Products += ":"+vehicleInfo.owner;

            var test = s.Products;
            console.log(test);


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for(var key in vehicleData){
    var test = /* ... */;
    console.log(test);
}
```

Use

```
var test = [];
for(var key in vehicleData){
    test.push(/* ... */);
}
console.log(test.join(', '));
```